# UserDefaults encoding fails

Tags: ios, swift

When storing complex data into UserDefaults, I get an exception. The code is as below.

The exception happens when the variable c is being written.

```
struct MyData : Codable {
  var v1 : Int
  var v2 : Int
  var v3 : Int
}


final class AllData : NSObject {

  var a : Int =  0

  var b  = [String : Int]()
  var c  = [String : MyData]()



  func loadSettings()
  {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let v = userDefaults.object(forKey: “A”) as? Int {
      self.a = v
    }


    if let v = userDefaults.object(forKey: “B”) as? [String : Int] {
      self.b = v
    }


    guard let decodedNSData = userDefaults.object(forKey: “C”) as? NSData,
      let v = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedNSData as Data) as? [String : MyData]? )!
      else {
        print("Failed decoding level information")
        return
    }
    self.c = v

  }


  func saveSettings()
  {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    userDefaults.set(self.a, forKey: “A”)
    userDefaults.set(self.b, forKey: “B”)
    userDefaults.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.c), forKey: “C”)
    userDefaults.synchronize()
  }
```

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is the exception message? Have you implemented archiving and unarchiving for `MyData`.

Comment: the error is "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".  MyData conforms to Codable

Comment: Please provide the full text of the exception and indicate which line causes the exception.

Comment: You need to make your class `NSCoding` compliant to be able to use `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Another option if you are using Xcode 9 or later is to use Codable protocol and save the json data

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using UserDefaults for storing your app data. You should use it only for persisting UI settings (your app preferences). Better to save your data into another property list file or if using Codable into a JSON file.

Comment: Note that Codable has nothing to do with NSKeyedArchiver. So if you want to make your class AllData NSCoding compliant you will need to declare MyData as a class and it will need also to inherit from NSObject and be compliant to NSCoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your struct implemnts codable then you better use **JSONEncoder** & **JSONDecoder**

```
struct Language: Codable {
var name: String
var version: Int
}

 let swift = Language(name: "Swift", version: 4)
 let encoder = JSONEncoder()
 if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(swift) {
// save `encoded` somewhere
}

if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(swift) {
if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
   print(json)
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 if let decoded = try? decoder.decode(Language.self, from: encoded) {
    print(decoded.name)
 }
```